# php preg_match to extract a string in the middle of another string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract a string from this string:

```
...width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F84915247&amp;color=da1716&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=true"...
```

All I want is the URL portion:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F84915247&amp
```

This is the regex I made:

```
$regex = "/^httpamp$/", but it does not work.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work:

```
$regex = '~url=\K\S+?&amp~';
```

(the `\K` feature keeps only characters after its position)

or with a lookbehind:

```
$regex = '~(?<=url=)\S+?&amp~';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
/url=([^ ]*)/
```

The URL would be in the 1st capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to parse HTML text with a regex, better to use DOM parser.

However if you know what you're doing then use following regex:

```
~\?url=([^;]+)~
```

Your desired URL is available in matched group # 1.

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/yiqtviBaSd

Answer (score 0):

@anubhava solution is good, but I've tweaked it to improve it, and to support the new iframe HTML5 SoundCloud embed code.

```
\?url=([^"]+)
```

That will match the url but not the trailing quotation marks. This way a user could input a SoundCloud widget, then the code would strip out the widget leaving only url on the input.

Then when you render to screen (output from your db), a second script could be written to match a SoundCloud url beginning with http://api.soundcloud.com and wrap it in the widget.